# Pathogen does not load plugins

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Pathogen does not work for me. I am following Adam Lowe's hints posted [here](http://www.adamlowe.me/2009/12/vim-destroys-all-other-rails-editors.html) (and few more) without any success...

My vimrc:

```
filetype off
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

filetype plugin indent on
set nocompatible
syntax on
set tabstop=2
set smarttab
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set expandtab
set number
colorscheme darkblue
```

Contents of .vim - `ls .vim/*`:

```
.vim/autoload:
pathogen.vim

.vim/bundle:
nerdcommenter/  vim-haml/   vim-surround/
vim-endwise/    vim-rails/  vim-vividchalk/
```

All plugins in bundle were installed by cloning them from GitHub into bundle directory.

I have tried with pathogen 1.1 and 1.2 and even the latest from GitHub without any result. Vividchalk, Vim-rails and nerdcommenter are not working. I have very little experience with other plugs so I am not sure about them, but I suppose they are not working too.

I am using ArchLinux, vim 7.2.385-1 (not the latest because the latest requires me to install ruby1.9, but it is still 7.2). It has been installed via pacman - ArchLinux package manager. No vim plugins were installed the other way than using pathogen (I have even reinstalled vim package with cleaning `/usr/share/vim`).

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

- `/etc/vimrc` http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=29685#a29685
- `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim`  http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=29686#a29686

Comment: You aren't using vim-sessions by chance, are you? I'm using sessions and pathogen didn't seem to work unless I created a new vim and didn't load a session but created a new one.

Comment: Just Vividchalk, Vim-rails and nerdcommenter aren't working? Do the others work?

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  A lot of plugins are working, though nerdcommenter does not... I wonder if NERD_commenter is being loaded when filetype is off and that's ruining things?

Comment: I have just moved from ArchLinux to Mac OS X. Most plugins started to work, NERD_commenter still does not. I think the problem with NERD_commenter is different from problem I had on Arch - not having plugins loaded at all. The fact I changed OS also means that I will have no possibility to check your hints. Thanks for help.

Comment: I don't know if this will help anyone else, but I had misplaced my `.vimrc` file under `~/.vim/.vimrc` instead of `~/.vimrc`. I spent way too long debugging that.

Answer (score 31):

This seems to be common problem caused by the "system" vimrc in some distributions setting `filetype on` before you set up pathogen. So turning it off and back on again forces plugins to load correctly:

```
 call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
 filetype off
 syntax on
 filetype plugin indent on
```

More info [here](http://blog.darevay.com/2010/10/a-brief-note-on-pathogen-for-vim/).

Comment: `call pathogen#infect()` which can be used in the latest version of pathogen now deals with this `filetype` problem (and is much easier to remember and type than `runtime_append_all_bundles`).

Comment: I suspect the `runtime_append_all_bundle` no longer exists in pathogen. You should change it to `incubate`. Or use `infect` as suggested by @Araxia .

Answer (score 24):

I was having a similar problem. Pathogen was loading some of my plugins while not all of them.
After some fiddling and wondering I discovered (I don't know if it's mentioned in the documentation) that in each `bundle/'plugin_name'` folder, there should be another folder called `plugin` that contains the *.vim file.

Then, when vim starts will look, not in bundle, but in those folders within bundle that contain a folder called plugin... and will create other folders (in each plugin folder).

So, if the plugin is just a .vim file make a folder for it...

instead of:

```
~/.vim/bundle/vimexplorer/vimExplorer.vim
```

you need:

```
~/.vim/bundle/vimexplorer/plugin/vimExplorer.vim
```

And everything works like a charm.

Comment: This was exactly my problem: The plugin source tree contained a directory called 'ftplugin'. I just created a symlink to it called 'plugin' and now everything works as expected.

Comment: same with other kinds of plugins like colorschemes. They require a `colors` folder, mirroring the `$VIM/vimfiles` directory. Pathogen works by adding each plugin root folder to Vim's runtimepath setting, which Vim then traverses looking for layouts that it expects in '$VIM/vimfiles'

Answer (score 14):

I've had problems loading particular plugins: specifically, plugins with a `plugin` subdirectory. For example, on a fresh MacVim install, a plugin in `~/.vim/bundle/surround/plugin/surround.vim` wasn't being loaded, even though `~/.vim/bundle/surround` appeared in the output of `:scriptnames`.

The problem was that I was loading Pathogen in `.gvimrc`, not `.vimrc`. For whatever reason, stuff in `.vim/bundle/*/plugin` subdirectories won't load if you do that, so do it in `.vimrc`!

I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/20) on github—I don't know if it can be made to work even if it loads from `.gvimrc`, but there should at least be some sort of warning in the documentation for idiots like me.

Comment: Changing from _gvimrc to .vimrc fixed mine problem! Thank you!

Comment: Moving these lines from `.gvimrc` to `.vimrc` got it working for me.

`call pathogen#infect()`
`filetype plugin indent on`

Answer (score 11):

If your .vim is based on a git repo and submodules, DO REMEMBER to run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` after cloning the repo. i.e.

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

I had the same error and tried all of the above, but it didn't work.  Until I initialized and updated the git submodules.

Hope this helps for anyone who has a similar error.

Comment: As un-related as this looks to vim, if you used git to add the vim plugins as submodules, a clean init and update is the only way to proceed. Even if you already have a copy of the directories in place from a previous installation.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe Arch's default vimrc (possibly `/etc/vim/vimrc`) doesn't play well with Pathogen. Try starting Vim without loading config files:

```
vim -u NONE
```

and then load your vimrc from within vim:

```
:so ~/.vimrc
```

Do the plugins work then?

Comment: I am getting error E117 that `pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles` and `pathogen#helptags` are unknown functions. Loading pathogen with `:so .vim/autoload/pathogen.vim` before loading `.vimrc` does not help. Commenting everything in `/etc/vimrc` does not help. Substituting `/etc/vimrc` with standard example vimrc does not help. Thanks for your effords.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix it? I have the same problem now using Ubuntu.

Comment: Yeah I have the same problem too. Installed http://github.com/akitaonrails/vimfiles. On Ubuntu 10.10. gVim 7.2.330

Comment: I'm having the same problem under Ubuntu 10.10. Anyone get it working?

Comment: This solved my problem: http://blog.darevay.com/2010/10/a-brief-note-on-pathogen-for-vim/

Comment: @Christian Joudrey, the link you gave is dead.

Answer (score 6):

Fixed by (mattn & tpope) after raising issue via github

```
set nocp
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
call pathogen#infect()
```

see https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/50#issuecomment-3137909

Answer (score 3):

My environment is Vim 7.3.35 and Ubuntu 11.04.

I spent some time trying to resolve it. I clone the project https://github.com:r00k/dotfiles and follow the instructions to install.

When started **vi** a got the so commented

> E117: Unknown function: pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles

and the solution:

> filetype off
>
> call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
>
> filetype on

did not work.

I found the **.vim** symlink in my home directory where no properly set. The install script made a **.vim** DIRECTORY with a symlink **vim** inside of it pointing to my **.dotfiles/vim**. The solution was to delete the **.vim** directory and make a symlink **.vim** pointing **.dotfiles/vim**.

A kept the filetype off/on in my **.vimrc** also.

Answer (score 2):

```
filetype off                                                                
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to check your runtime path using command:
:set runtimepath?
First entry should be something like ~/.vim.

My problem with not loading plugins/pathogen was that i placed my vim environment in ~/.dotfiles/vim where my vimrc and rest of the stuff (plugins etc.) lives.
After creating symlink to ~/.dotfiles/vim/vimrc in ~/.vimrc i forgot to make second symlink ~/.vim -> ~/.dotfiles/vim/ which caused vim to be confused cause he was looking for stuff in ~/.vim (default). After i made proper symlink everything poped in right place.

I hope it will help someone who forgot about second symlink like I did ;-)

Comment: Had the same problem in Git for Windows after switching from Git Bash. Git Bash had the files in `~/vimfiles`. Changed the name to `~/.vim`, and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()`, I used `call pathogen#infect('~/.vim/bundle')` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with Ubuntu. The log was:

```
linha 4: executando "/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftoff.vim"
Erro detectado ao processar /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftoff.vim:
linha   11:
E216: Grupo ou evento inexistente: filetypedetect *
fim da execução de /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftoff.vim
```

The solution was to add "\n"s at the end from file /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftoff.vim to execute it properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
set nocp
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
call pathogen#infect()
```

The above helped me fix the issue, can't leave a comment on other peoples however thank you for posting the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I have it in mine as:

> silent! call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

Answer (score 0):

After spending waaaay too long trying to solve this problem with nerd-commenter/pathogen, I broke down and just used Debian's OS provided nerd-commenter plugin:

```
vim-addons install nerd-commenter
```

If you're on Debian and need to get back to work, try it out.  You probably need "vim-addon-manager" and "vim-scripts" packages installed from apt if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion I'll add my solution for this problem.

I just renamed my ~/.gvimrc file to ~/.vimrc, and all my problems were solved. I literally copied my .vim and my .gvimrc from linux and did this change and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried every possible combination.

Finally I found that if I use `mksession` to save my Vim workspace and have it load on Vim startup, it made pathogen not load new plugins I put into the bundle folder.

After installing a new plugin I now always delete my session file and start Vim fresh and every plugin loads fine.

```
filetype off
set nocompatible
set laststatus=2
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I cloned to a folder ~/dotfiles but vun looks for a folder ~/.vim, as a result he carried no plugins or color schemes to solve the problem I did this:

```
ln -s ~/.dotfiles ~/.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem , solved by copying this file into ~/.vim/autoload:
https://github.com/sontek/dotfiles/blob/master/_vim/autoload/pathogen.vim

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, finally after lot of google and tweaking the vimrc file, found the solution. Hope the following code snippet would resolve the issue.

`set nocp
source /home/ameet/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim "location of my pathogen.vim
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()`