# pathogen not loading nerdtree

Tags: vim, loading, nerdtree

I've got pathogen in .vim/autoload and i've got nerdtree within my .vim/bundles directory. I've also got

```
filetype off
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
filetype plugin indent on
```

in my .vimrc file

for whatever reason though, when i run vim, NERDTree doesn't run.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is NERDTree really within `.vim/bundles`? It should be in `.vim/bundle`.

<sub>Also, note that you should put the `call pathogen#helptags()` line *after* the `call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()` line, or it won't generate tags properly. I'm not sure why so many blogposts about pathogen have it the other way around.</sub>

Comment: LOL, thanks a million. Now it's in /bundle and not /bundles and it's working.

Comment: @user578994 Glad to hear it :)

Comment: @user578994: Welcome to this site! If an answer actually solves your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted (that checkmark right below the answer votes).

Comment: Moving pathogen#infect() from gvimrc to vimrc fixed this for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383502/pathogen-does-not-load-plugins