# NERDTree on windows

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have installed nerdtree using pathogen as per instruction given in the github site.

The packages are located under /vimfiles/bundle as shown below.

```
/Vim/vimfiles/bundle
$ ls
nerdtree  python-mode  vim-pathogen-master
```

I have added the below lines to my _vimrc file

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
filetype off
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

But still when I try using NerdTree I get a not an editor command error. It would be great if you could help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You didn't follow the instructions *and* you cloned both pathogen and nerdtree in the wrong directory.

*Your* configuration (vimrc/plugins/colorschemes/…) should be in *your* `%UserProfile%` directory:

```
%UserProfile%\vimfiles\
%UserProfile%\_vimrc
```

On Windows XP:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\karthikbharadwaj\vimfiles\
C:\Documents and Settings\karthikbharadwaj\_vimrc
```

On Windows Vista/7/8:

```
C:\Users\karthikbharadwaj\vimfiles\
C:\Users\karthikbharadwaj\_vimrc
```

Pathogen's `README` is very clear about what to install, where to install it and what lines you must add to your `%UserProfile%\_vimrc`; I have no idea where you got that `runtime_append_all_bundles()` idea.

The file `pathogen.vim` should be in `%UserProfile%\vimfiles\autoload\`.

Your `%UserProfile%\_vimrc` should look like:

```
filetype off

execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until I changed my vimrc to add the following line;
call pathogen#infect()

Similar to [Pathogen does not load plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383502/pathogen-does-not-load-plugins)